# Preparing polyurethane with IPDI (Isophorone Diisocyanate)

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I am trying to prepare a polyurethane using hydroxy-terminated polybutadiene (a polyol) and IPDI (a diisocyanate) as the curing agent. I intend to use DBTDL as a catalyst. I read that both IPDI and DBTDL are very toxic and dangerous to use. Being a non-chemistry student, I do not have a lot of experience dealing with chemicals. Could someone point to finer details involved in the process (things like the PPE used, whether the reaction needs to be done in a fumehood, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) for any unanswered questions about it.